# Formatting a float to string at constructor level

Tags: c#

I have a constructor that builds a table. The way the data is fed in is quite complex and depends on previous data. One of my columns displays a float that I would like to format as currency. I want to do this at the level where it is get and set, so when I get or set the data I'm working with a float, but when it's displayed it's a formatted string. I have the methods to convert into and convert back into the desired format. How can I implement them?

**Example Code**

```
public class WarehouseItem
{
    public WarehouseItem(int id, int parentID, string clientID, string instrumentID, string orderID, string status, float openPosition, float execPosition, float cumOpenPosition, float cumExecPosition, string time, string logTime)
    {    
        this.OpenPosition = openPosition;
    }

    public float OpenPosition
    {
        get; // returns float (retroConvert)
        set; // takes a float -> string (convert)
    }

    private float retroConvert(string input)
    {
        string str = input.Replace(",", "");
        return float.Parse(str);
    }

    private string convert(float input)
    {
        return ((float)input).ToString("#,##0.00");
    }  
}
```

Comment: Side note: what you trying to do is generally bad idea. Usually you store data in most suitable format (`decimal` for currency values) internally and only format them during output (usually by code external to your data item class). If you really want to go the way you trying to please at least use culture-aware formatting/parsing and avoid `.Replace(",","")` and hardcoded output format, consider "C" specifier for currency formatting too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use another field that only has a getter to return the formatted string.

Eg.

```
public string OpenPositionFormatted
{
    get { return convert(OpenPosition); }
}
```